# How to copy CSV to Json that has column header with dot in ADF?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm working with Copy activity in Adf that takes CSV as source and sink it as a Json. I notice that when the CSV column header name has a dot in between (e.g abc.def.ghi), it is converting the header as hierarchy instead of taking it as a plain string header.
[image]

Is there a way I could handle this to get just the column name as per the csv file?

Comment: please check `First row as header` property in source dataset

Comment: First row as header is already checked. The issue is when we do the import schema mapping, its shows it is mapped with the header but when i check the json file output it showing the header hierarchy as above.

Comment: Is just the header separated with dots? Data is separated with commas?

Comment: the header is coming with dot, the data is separate with semicolon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be by design. A workaround is to manually edit the column header in imported mapping schema, removing the dot and replacing by `_`  But if you would like to retain the column header as `abc.def.ghi` you can try DataFlow.

**Sample Source:**

[image]

**Original output: Just using copy activity**

[image]

**Workarounds:**

## Manually edit schema mapping for sink:

[image]

[image]

OR

## Use DataFlow with Auto mapping and Output to single file:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks Karthik. You have exactly defined my problem. Unfortunately, I cant remove the dot and replace it with anything else as it is a unique header that I need to pass in the json file. I did read about data flow that allows me to do this but I thought it was an overkill just to get a column header hence the reason I raised a question if there's alternative to this issue.

Comment: am afraid given the combination of source and sink i.e. csv to json there are no much options. You would have to use DataFlow or external function or rename column as a workaround. I tried unchecking `First row as header` and maaping JSON in advanced editor and using escape characters or dynamically explicitly providing schema as JSON in mapping but same results.  Let me know if you found a solution

Comment: for now, as an alternative im passing the json info to the azure function to deal with this issue. I believe I could do much more with with C# code than the UI.

Comment: you can say that again 

Comment: just an update, in ADF the data flow will not work for self-hosted integration runtime. In my case, the csv is hosted on-premise so data flow unfortunately would not be an option.

Comment: 1. Self hosted integration runtime is not supported as a source in data flows. Instead, use copy activity to stage the data in azure blob or ADLS and then use data flows with that Dataset 2. Vnet support across ADF is on the roadmap. In the meantime, you can use a VM with self-hosted IR inside your VNET, then drop the data in a Blob or ADLS folder. Of course, that target folder cannot be in a Vnet for Data Flow to use it for now.

Comment: You can check [this](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/35923#:~:text=Self%20hosted%20integration%20runtime%20is%20not%20supported%20as,and%20then%20use%20data%20flows%20with%20that%20Dataset.) for more

Comment: Hi Karthik, thank you for the advise. Yes the solution above work! The only problem now is the json file ends up as separate set of json objects. This is causing a problem while reading as it is not a valid json. Do you know how to make it as an array of objects instead in data flow?

Comment: [snip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9d661.png) Select the source > source option (tab) > JSON setting (expand option below) > Document form : Array of documents

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response. I see that this option is only applicable for the source as Json and not for CSV but that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to an Azure Synapse Analytics workspace then [serverless SQL pools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/on-demand-workspace-overview) can read the .csv and convert it to JSON without the unintentional hierarchy side-effect, by using `FOR JSON AUTO`:

```
SELECT [abc.def.ghi]
FROM OPENROWSET (
    BULK 'https://someL.dfs.core.windows.net/filesystem/raw/colwithdot.csv',
    FORMAT = 'CSV',
    PARSER_VERSION = '2.0',
    HEADER_ROW = TRUE
    ) AS [result]
FOR JSON AUTO, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER;
```

My results:

[image: My results]

You could use this statement as a source in a Copy activity or try `CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE AS (CETAS)` in Synapse ([untested](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/develop-tables-cetas)).